# Missing template error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am stuck in a problem:

```
 respond_to do |format|
     format.html {render :partial => 'students/list', :locals => {:roll_nos =>        
    @roll_numbers}, :layout => false}
 end
```

I have created _list.html.haml inside app/views/students folder. But it is repeatedly showing **missing template** error. I have no idea. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

you have to render fully not partially. Or `redirect_to` to a url. :)

So create another action inside this `controller`, like:

```
def list
  #do others...
end
```

and create `list.html.haml`, inside `app/views/students` folder.

add this action to `routes.rb` like:

```
resources :students do
  get :list
end
```

try without partial:

```
 respond_to do |format|
     format.html {render :list, :layout => false}
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't render a partial in a controller, you either render the default view, a template, a file, render inline or render nothing as described in the documentation

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

if you want to use the partial, just render it in your default view template for the action.

```
respond_to do |format|
     format.html {render :layout => false}
end
```

OR

create a template list.html.haml in the students folder and render the partial within the template. Difference between a partial and a template file name is that the partial has an underscore in front of it and by that is recognized as a partial

```
#students/list.html.haml
render :partial => 'students/list', :locals => {:roll_nos =>        
@roll_numbers}
```

And in in your controller you render the template

```
respond_to do |format|
     format.html {render :template => 'students/list', :layout => false}
end
```